# arc circle with smooth/perfect circle edges

Tags: html, three.js, geometry

I have this this arc circle model, but I want the edges not to be cut but rather look like a smooth circle, and somehow increase the edge segments which is called tobular segment when using [TorusGeometry](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/geometries/TorusGeometry)

How can I do that with arc circle? here is my [codepen](https://codepen.io/ZhyarZy/pen/VwByeEq?editors=1111)

[image]

is that even possible?
is there a better way to approach this?

HTML

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body style="margin: 0px; overflow: hidden; text-align:center;">
    <div id = "fivesides">
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Three.js

```
 //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//      Init
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// init renderer
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    antialias: true
});

renderer.setClearColor(new THREE.Color(0xdadae5), 1);
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
// array of functions for the rendering loop
var onRenderFcts = [];
// init scene and camera
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
    45,
    window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
    0.01,
    1000
);
camera.position.z = 2;
var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera);
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//      add an object in the scene
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
var colors = [0x114575,0x1067AD,0x64A7D7];
var dimensions = [0.1,0.2,0.3];


let shape = new THREE.Shape();
let width, height, x, y, radius;
const pos = new THREE.Vector3();

var  previewSizes = [];
 previewSizes[0] = 20;
 previewSizes[1] = 10;

shape.moveTo( 5, 1 );
shape.absarc( 1, 1, 4, 0, Math.PI * 2, false );
const holePath = new THREE.Path();
holePath.moveTo( 2, 1 );
holePath.absarc( 1, 1, 1, 0, Math.PI * 2, true );
shape.holes.push( holePath );

var settings = { };
settings.depth = 0.4;
settings.bevelEnabled = false;


var geometry = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry( shape, settings );
//var geometry = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(shape);

var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    color: 0x1067AD,
    vertexColors: THREE.FaceColors
});

//[red, Yellow,purple]
var colorSet = [0x114575, 0x1067AD, 0x64A7D7];

for (var i = 0; i < geometry.faces.length; i++) {
  if (geometry.faces[i].normal.y == 0) {
    geometry.faces[i].color.setHex(colorSet[2]);
  } else if (geometry.faces[i].normal.x == 0) {
    geometry.faces[i].color.setHex(colorSet[0]);
  } else {
    geometry.faces[i].color.setHex(colorSet[1]);
  }
}

var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

scene.add(mesh);


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//      render the whole thing on the page
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// handle window resize
window.addEventListener(
    "resize",
    function() {
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
        camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    },
    false
);
// render the scene
onRenderFcts.push(function() {
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
});

// run the rendering loop
var lastTimeMsec = null;
requestAnimationFrame(function animate(nowMsec) {
    // keep looping
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    // measure time
    lastTimeMsec = lastTimeMsec || nowMsec - 1000 / 60;
    var deltaMsec = Math.min(200, nowMsec - lastTimeMsec);
    lastTimeMsec = nowMsec;
    // call each update function
    onRenderFcts.forEach(function(onRenderFct) {
        onRenderFct(deltaMsec / 1000, nowMsec / 1000);
    });
});
```

Thanks

Comment: When using 3D meshes, you're always limited by a certain level of detail. Traditional 3D geometry cannot have infinite precision, so your circle will never be infinitely smooth. There are pretty complex ways to achieve this with custom shaders, or signed distance fields (SDFs), but that's a whole course in of itself. I recommend you just add more subdivisions to your geometry to accommodate the level of zoom you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after lots more research and talking with some other devs, here is the solution.
hopefully someone can use this:

first declaring some variables:

```
let shape = new THREE.Shape();
let width, height, x, y, radius;
const pos = new THREE.Vector3();
var axesHelper = new THREE.AxesHelper(16);
var previewSizes = [40, 20, 40]

var outerRadius = previewSizes[0] / 100;
var innerRadius = previewSizes[1] / 100;

// the more segments , the better the outlines
var segments = 100;
var angle = (2 * Math.PI) / segments;
```

shape the x and y lines calculating the  **inner/outer** Radius with **cos** and **sin**
The **Math.cos()** static method returns the cosine of a number in radians.
The **Math.sin()** static method returns the sine of a number in radians.

```
shape.moveTo(outerRadius, 0);
for (let i = 1; i <= segments; i++) {
    x = outerRadius * Math.cos(angle * i);
    y = outerRadius * Math.sin(angle * i);
shape.lineTo(x, y);
}

var hole = new THREE.Path();
hole.moveTo(innerRadius, 0);
for (let i = 1; i <= segments; i++) {
    x = innerRadius * Math.cos(angle * i);
    y = innerRadius * Math.sin(angle * i);
    hole.lineTo(x, y);
}
shape.holes.push(hole);
```

also made a demo: [codepen](https://codepen.io/ZhyarZy/pen/qByxoZW)